# Correct nameservers in resolv.conf but no hostname resolution

Tags: networking, dns

As said in the title I can't resolve hostnames when doing a "ping google.com" even though the content of /etc/resolv.conf seems correct :

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

I am connected to WiFi network through wicd-curses which correctly populate the resolv.conf file. This grants me internet access as a "ping 216.58.208.238" (google) works as expected. So it is as if my resolv.conf file is not read to resolve hostnames and I can't understand why.

Thank you !

**Edit:** After further inquiring, I think I must describe more clearly my setting because it seems to be the cause of the problem. I have a laptop which gets internet access through wireless. It is connected by wire to another private network. I have another host with a wireless connection to this network and from which I want to access the internet. This is on this host I can't resolve hostnames.

Well, if I change my nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf to the same nameserver as in resolv.conf on my laptop, it works great. What am I missing to do it automatically ? And why doesn't it work with google nameservers ?

Comment: Can you resolve hostnames directly from the command line? Try this: host www.google.com 8.8.4.4 . The result will tell you if your computer can connect to the DNS server.

Comment: Not sure, but try executing `sudo resolvconf -u` in a terminal. A reboot should solve it anyway if it is no serious configuration problem. But DNS resolving us usually pretty dynamically done and therefore such fails sometimes come and leave without a reason (at least it looks like this to me.)

Comment: `host www.google.com 8.8.4.4` didn't work, I obtained "connection timed out; no servers could be reached".

As for `resolconf -u` and a reboot it didn't work either.